# How to add customers email to transactional emails content

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

How do I add the customers e-mail to the sales transaction e-mail? At the moment I include the shipping and billing details but these only include the address and telephone number. How do I add the customers email address (I can't see the variable on the admin side) - is it something I need to do in FTP?

The current setup is as follows:

```
  {{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
  {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="email-heading">
                    <h1>Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                    <p>Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.</p>
                </td>
                <td class="store-info">
                    <h4>Order Questions?</h4>
                    <p>
                        {{depend store_phone}}
                        <b>Call Us:</b>
                        <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                        {{/depend}}
                        {{depend store_hours}}
                        <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                        {{/depend}}
                        {{depend store_email}}
                        <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                        {{/depend}}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="order-details">
        <h3>Your order <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
        <p>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="order-information">
    <td>
        {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
            <tr>
                <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{/if}}
        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6>Bill to:</h6>
                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                </td>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6>Ship to:</h6>
                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
          <td class="address-details">
                    <h6>Email:</h6>
                   <p>{{htmlescape myemail=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</p>
           </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
                    <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6>Payment method:</h6>
                    {{var payment_html}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
         {{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Comment: Awesome, What about the same variables but for Magento 2. That will be great.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134542)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order emails already have access to the order object. So any field or value of an order can be accessed in the mail.

In this case that would be `{{var order.customer_email}}`

Answer (score 8):

I'll leave you here several variables in case you need them:

**- For registration:**

```
{{var customer}} Will print out all customer information

{{var customer.ID}}

{{var customer.email}}

{{var customer.firstname}}

{{var customer.lastname}}

{{var customer.name}}

{{var customer.password}}

{{var customer.created_in}} Store Name

{{var customer.dob}} Date of Birth

{{var customer.password_hash}}

{{var customer.prefix}}

{{var customer.middlename}} Initial

{{var customer.suffix}}

{{var customer.group_id}}

{{var customer.taxvat}}

{{var customer.store.name}} What store they registered with (On Demo store this will display as ‘English’

{{var customer.store.group.name}} The actual Store’s name (not the Store View’s)
```

**- To subscribe/unsubscribe newsletter:**

```
{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}

{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}

{{var subscriber.email}}
```

**- Send to a friend:**

```
{{var product_image}}

{{var name}} Recipient’s Name

{{var email}} Recipient’s Email

{{var product_name}} Product Name

{{var product_url}} Product Url

{{var message}} Message Text

{{var sender_name}} Sender’s Name

{{var sender_email}} Sender’s Email

{{var product_image}} Product Image
```

**- Block**

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

**- Depend Condition**

```
{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

{{/depend}}

{{depend salable}}

{{/depend}}
```

**- If Condition**

```
{{if order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

(else is optional)

**- Skin**

```
{{skin url="'}}
```

**- Store**

```
{{store url=""}}
```

**- New order : Shipping Address**

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
```

**Items of the shipping address :**

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getName()}} Get the first and last name

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPrefix()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getFirstName()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getMiddleName()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getLastName()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getSuffix()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet1()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet2()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCity()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPostcode()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}} Get the country’s ID

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountryModel().getName()}} Get the country’s full name

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}}

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getTelephone()}}
```

**- Other**

```
{{var addAllLink}}

{{var alertGrid}}

{{var billingAddress.format('html')}}

{{var checkoutType}}

{{var comment}}

{{var creditmemo.id}}

{{var creditmemo.increment_id}}

{{var data.comment}}

{{var data.email}}

{{var data.name}}

{{var data.telephone}}

{{var dateAndTime}}

{{var invoice.id}}

{{var invoice.increment_id}}

{{var invoice.created_at}}

{{var items}}

{{var items_html}}

{{var message}}

{{var name}}

{{var order.customer_email}}

{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}

{{var order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}

{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}

{{var order.getCustomerName()}}

{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}

{{var order.getCustomerLastname()}}

{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}} Currently unknwon how to test this variable for being set/empty

{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}

{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}

{{var order.getStoreGroupName()}}

{{var order.id}}

{{var order.increment_id}}

{{var password}}

{{var payment_html}}

{{var paymentMethod}}

{{var product_name}}

{{var product_url}}

{{var reason}} Reason for payment failure

{{var shipment.increment_id}}

{{var shippingAddress.format('html')}}

{{var shippingMethod}}

{{var total}}

{{var user.name}}

{{var viewOnSiteLink}}

{{var warnings}}

{{var billing.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every option which I found here, but nothing worked. After some research I found customer email in **billing** variable {{var billing.email}}